# Rselenium: ‘sendKeystoElement’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “webElement”

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to insert a keyword into a search box on a website by using RSelenium:

```r
library(RSelenium)

#Opens the Browser and nafigates to SHAB
driver <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
remoteDriver <- driver[["client"]]

remoteDriver$navigate("https://shab.ch/#!/search/publications")

#Find Form Elements and fill insert the parameters
keyword <- "(nouveau+capital-actions)-reduction|(aktienkapital+neu)-herabgesetzt|(nuovo+capitale+azionario)-riduzione)"
element<- remoteDriver$findElement("id", "keyword")
element$sendKeystoElement(list(keyword))
```

However when I try to execute the code in RStudio I always get this error:

```
> element$sendKeystoElement(list(keyword))
Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) : 
  ‘sendKeystoElement’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “webElement”
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You simply made a typo: it's not `sendKeystoElement` but `sendKeysToElement`.